# PHPUnit showing passed methods that throws Fatal Error Exception

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I am having problem with PHPUnit on Netbeans where few methods are showing as passed when the method throws some exception like Fatal error or something.

So it seems that PhpUnit cannot handle these exception and it just marks them as passed.

This would work fine

```
$this->assertEquals(true, 1 == 2);
```

Failed asserting that false matches expected true.

but if I add some code that throws some exception then it just marks it as passed as an example:

```
 public function testEquals() {
     thisMethodDoesNotExists(5);
 }
```

It marks this as passed where it should not cz there is a fatal error.

Comment: is your result changed when you run phpunit on command-line? 
 https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/textui.html

Comment: @kuromoka it actually does not show anything related to phpunit test results it only shows fatal error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function var_dumb()

Comment: this annotation might be useful for you. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/annotations.html#runinseparateprocess

Comment: looks like the annotation did the trick :) thanks alot

Comment: u can add as an answe

Comment: thanks for choosing as good answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation.
Please see details.
https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/annotations.html#runinseparateprocess.

Comment: it works by adding this annotation, do u know if there is any option that I can configure on netbeans so I dont have to add this annotation into all tests, a collegue of mine does not use the annotation and it still works for her!