# PHPUnit is showing test as passed when there are Fatal Exception Errors

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, phpunit

I am using Netbeans 8.2 and PHPUnit 4.8.36 along with PHP 5.6.36 and I have some issue when there is some Fatal Error Exception within the tests functions.

```
 /**
  * @runInSeparateProcess
  */
  public function testEquals() {
    thisMethodDoesNotExistsAndTestShouldFail();
  }
```

It works fine if I add the annotation **@runInSeparateProcess** so that means test fails.

But if I have it just like this:

```
public function testEquals() {
        thisMethodDoesNotExistsAndTestShouldFail();
}
```

The test passes which in my opinion is wrong.

The idea is that I don't want to add the annotations for each test and there are hundred of tests already so I can't just go and add to every of them.

Is there any way that I can configure PHPUnit to run the tests in separate process.

For ex my colleague of mine doesnt need to add this annotation and it works for her as expected.

Any idea where I should look this to solve or anyone had this issue before? Do u think the php version would matter here, since my colleague is using php 5.3.x and it works for her. Also I am using Zend Framework v1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit showing passed methods that throws Fatal Error Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554619/phpunit-showing-passed-methods-that-throws-fatal-error-exception)

Comment: @RobbieAverill its not the same question, well its quite similar but I am asking something else here, probably I should modify the title of question!